# Is there any way to insert array element to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am little confuse about to insert the array element in mysql

```
i have a array as following
  $a = array(
        '1' => 'a',
        '2' => 'b',
        '3' => 'c',
        '4' => 'd',
        '5' => 'e'
        '6' => 'f'
    );
```

and i have a table field id1,id2,...may be

```
id1   id2
a      b
c      d
e      f
```

can any one help me out with php code.

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: unable to get the proper way to insert.

Comment: How does your query and the code you have written so far look? Please past it here, so we can help you improve it.

Comment: Do you want to store array values in 2 columns (only) table?

Comment: no multiple column, as the column increase than the data also divided as well

Comment: If column count is dynamic, then you have to get the column count "n". Using For loop with incremental value "n", you can insert a record on each loop run. It's just an idea. Not an ultimate solution.

Comment: exactly i was thinking the same....but struggling...

Comment: @madhurjya then post your code in question.

Comment: Are you trying to insert array as value in a field or you want to create columns in table dynamically?

Comment: @ askkirati i am trying to insert array as value to table but the table has dynamic columns

Comment: @madhurjya did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you, I really appreciate your effort to give your precious time to fix my situation,  finally I had use the array_chunk function to divide my array to multiple sub array same with column no, than I insert the array value by sub key by for each loop.thank you thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this short tutorial. It might be just what you need: http://99webtools.com/how-to-store-array-mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

If the table persists out of 2 columns only, `id1` and `id2`

You could do the following:

```
$insertVals = ''; //Values go here,
$insertCols = ''; //Column names go here, alternating from id1 to id2

$counter = 0; //Will be used to iterate odd and even.

foreach ($a as $value) {
    $insertVals .= "'".$value."',"; //Comma at the end is needed.
    if ($counter % 2 == 0) //if even basicly
      $insertCols .= 'id1,'; //DB fields do not require quotes, backticks are optional
    else
      $insertCols .= 'id2,';
    $counter++ //Increment counter to cause odd values to occur.
}

//Remove last comma's from both strings.
$insertVals = substr($insertVals, 0, -1); //-1 removes the last char in substr.
$insertCols = substr($insertCols, 0, -1);

$query = "INSERT INTO yourtable ({$insertCols}) VALUES ({$insertVals})";
```

this should do the trick. Let me know if there are any errors you get since this is written straight out of the head and **untested**.

Regards, Sidney Liebrand

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but the used to iterate odd and even is not the exact way as i have multiple of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(
        '1' => 'a',
        '2' => 'b',
        '3' => 'c',
        '4' => 'd',
        '5' => 'e'
        '6' => 'f'
    );

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pw", "db");

foreach($a as $insert)
{
   $query = INSERT INTO table $insert[1],$insert[2];
   $mysqli=mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: [see reasons not use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: fixed, changed to msqli

Comment: This is not any better... Learn about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [how to prevent it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/747609)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? I just wanted to show what he needs to do, not how he should implement it in his actual code

Comment: *sigh* do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: It's **untested**

This will work for any number of columns.

```
<?php

$a = array(
    '1' => 'a',
    '2' => 'b',
    '3' => 'c',
    '4' => 'd',
    '5' => 'e'
    '6' => 'f'
);
$col_cnt = 3; // get column count from mysql query.
$temp = array();
for($i=0;$i<$col_cnt;$i++)
$temp[] = ''; //initialize the array. If no value in "a", then empty will inserted

for($t=1;$t<=count($a);$t+=$col_cnt)
{
$ins_arr = $temp; //initialize with empty values
for($j=0;$j<$col_cnt;$j++)
{
    $ins_arr[$j] = $a[$t+$j];
}
//
mysql_query("insert into tab1 values(".implode(",",$ins_arr).")");


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a little bit about Database_normalization  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization. Basicly you create a new table for the array and tie them together with a key.